# Rails: How to create Stackoverflow-style urls using Rails built-in "resources"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

Stackoverflow urls are like this one:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/name-of-user
```

It has all attributes of a true RESTful route:

```
:resource_name/:resource_id
```

But it also has a `name` part after a `:resource_id` segment. I know how to achieve it using a Non-Resourceful Routes of Rails. But is it possible to achieve the same urls using its built-in default `resources :user` methods?

By default the third segment is a format in Rails:

```
/users/:id(.:format)      users#show
```

Comment: FWIW, that extra string is often called a ["slug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it has it's own definition.

Comment: Yeah. Knowing what people usually call it will make searching for it much easier.

Comment: @Green, I know this is an old question , did you happen to find a way to do this with resources on your own?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it seems to still get some interests. So I'll post what I came up with.

I am not sure how far you want to be resourceful but this, with globing, works:

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    get '*slug', to: 'articles#show', as: 'slugged'
  end
end
```

This also works:

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    get ':slug', to: 'articles#show', as: 'slugged'
  end
end
```

In both case, you can then use

```
 <%= link_to slugged_article_path(article, article.title.parameterize) %>
```

in your views (you might want to define a virtual attribute in your model for the slug, instead of building it dynamically with `article.title.parameterize` in the view).

Note that so far, Rails will not complain if you enter anything as the slug in your browser.

I personally find the resourceful approach a bit verbose since I am only interested having pretty urls for the show actions (which are the only ones that may be seen by the regular users or the search engine bots) so I find it more simple to simply do:

```
resources :articles
get 'articles/:id/:slug', to: 'articles#show', as: 'slugged_article'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FriendlyId. there is a repository in [Github](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id) and well documented . Ryan bates also make a very good video tutorial about it in [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

Comment: As mentioned in the original question you can certainly do all of this without using resources easily enough, but friendly_id doesn't address setting up the routing using resources unless there's something specific you want to refer to within.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a controller `questions_controller`.

**In routes.rb:**

```
get 'questions/:id/:slug', to: 'questions#show'
```

**In questions_controller.rb:**

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  if request.path != question_path(@question)
    redirect_to @question, status: :moved_permanently
    return
  end
...
end
```

**In question.rb:**

```
def to_param
  "#{id}/#{name.parameterize}"
end
```

That's it. All generated paths will include the slug, and if try to access `/questions/42`, or `/questions/42/incorrect-slug`, you are redirected.

Comment: Original question, and same one I have, is how to do the same thing using resources, or if it's even possible.